# Dropdown Dates as List

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to make a dropdown list but for dates, something like date picker but more of a date picker. Some thing like the below link...

[image]

```
<input type="text">
```

The problem is a dropdown will give me only limited entries. So how can I work around this. Is there any way I change how the datepicker looks like.?

Comment: Would it work for you if you split it into day, month and year sections ?

Comment: why does your imgur link go to a blank jsfiddle?

Comment: @Sean fixed....Alp no it wont :/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create your own drop down from scratch and customize it as per your requirements.

however you have not given more details I can just give you some examples through which you can implement it.

You can also use jquery ui in which you can customize it to some extent.

[example1](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-create-cross-browser-datepickers-in-minutes--net-20236)
[example2](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-x1onO/0/1)

**Updated**

As you said in question that the problem of limited entries,

here is the  [fiddle](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/dipeshraichana/pomrz9dz/)
you can add as many entry as you want to add and just give it overflow property to adjust the height you want.

All you need to do is enter the values manually or you can use ajax call.

Comment: I know about the date picker...But how can i transform that into a list format? as shown in the image.
I was think of something using jQuery and adding dates to list if the user comes to end of the list... so display 5 dates, if user scrolls all the way to the bottom add 5  more..?
But how would I code that?

Comment: You should be able to build a simple form with a calendar control and then setup a connection between that and your list.  The connection will let you filter the target list based on the selection from the first web part.

You can use ajax calls and filter function for this purpose.you can hide your original date picker element so you can only show your list element

Comment: how can i know when user scrolled all the way to the bottom of a dropdown box, so I can dynamically add more values

Comment: yea fiddle doesnt help sorry

Comment: sorry for fiddle. Now its working. You dont need to get data on scroll. you can  load all data on page load. And if you want to load data on scroll event you can use wowjs.
http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Comment: but how can u do that in a dropdown menu?

Comment: you have to create your own drop down from scratch using ul and li. Just check my fiddle. hope I might understood your problem !! There is other solution which is create a dropdown for each element. i.e. date, month and year separately!!